# Can someone check my code and tell me why I'm getting error even after using correct code in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

It's a simple thing and I'm stuck here for days. I want to just return some text if the directory in the device doesn't exist but it just doesn't work? And you know small things always cause the biggest pain so I'm asking my fellow SO guys to help me with this. My entire code is [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/wastatussaver/tree/main/waapp2trialagain) .

[image]

And the main area where I'm facing issue is :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dialogs.dart';
import 'file_utils.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'navigate.dart';
import 'strings.dart';
import 'theme_config.dart';

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
startTimeout() {
return Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), handleTimeout);
}

void handleTimeout() {
changeScreen();
}

changeScreen() async {
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  requestPermission();
} else {
  Navigate.pushPageReplacement(context, MyHome());
}
}

requestPermission() async {
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
if (status.isGranted) {
  checkWAFolder();
} else {
  Dialogs.showToast('Please Grant Storage Permissions');
}
}

checkWAFolder(){
  if (Directory(FileUtils.waPath).existsSync()) {
  Navigate.pushPage(
    context,
    MyHome(),
  );
} else {
  Navigate.pushPage(context, NoMediaPage());
}
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
startTimeout();
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
    statusBarIconBrightness:
    Theme.of(context).primaryColor == ThemeConfig.darkTheme.primaryColor
        ? Brightness.light
        : Brightness.dark,
  ));
  });
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Feather.folder,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          size: 70.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        Text(
          "${AppStrings.appName}",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            fontSize: 25.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
      }
    }

class NoMediaPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: Container(child: Center(child: Text("Hello World!")),),
);
   }
```

}

The exception caught is:

```
The following FileSystemException was thrown building Builder:
Directory listing failed, path = 
'/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/' (OS Error: No such file or 
directory, errno = 2)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
MaterialApp-[#a8655] file:///D:/jidewasaver/lib/app.dart:13:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _Directory._fillWithDirectoryListing (dart:io- 
patch/directory_patch.dart:37:68)
#1      _Directory.listSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:243:5)
#2      new _MyHomeState (package:jidewasaver/homepage.dart:28:62)
#3      MyHome.createState (package:jidewasaver/homepage.dart:23:33)
#4      new StatefulElement 
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4584:24)
```

Comment: A priori it seems like you are not catching an exception whe opening the file . Try wrapping that code inside a try catch block. Probably inside `checkWAFolder`

Comment: i've edited my question with adding the `exception` can you please tell me where I need to "see"? I'm just confused a little.

Comment: oh it worked....i added `checkWAFolder` in `MaterialApp's` `home` property and now it's working fine. thank you so much. really appreciate your help.